# Lib error when trying to use a dll

Tags: c++, dll

I'm trying to create my own dll and use it in another project. I followed this [microsoft tutorial](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms235636.aspx)

My problem is when I build the testing project that call my dll file I get this error

```
LINK : fatal error LNK1104: cannot open file 'C:\Users\...\wrapperOpenCV.lib
```

I don't understand why the program expect a lib since I only build a dll.

Thanks for the help.

Comment: You though (still) need a ***stub interface*** to link against!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The linking process for compile time linking to a DLL is:

1. Build the DLL. This will output, amongst other things, the DLL itself and an import library, the .lib file.
2. Compile the program that uses the DLL. This will use the include files that declare the types and functions exported by the DLL.
3. Link the import library generated in step 1. This provides the definitions of the functions exported by the DLL.

You are asking the linker to link the import library, but it is not being found. Either it was not created, or the linker is looking in the wrong place for it.

Comment: Ok I guess my error come from the fact that the.lib file is not generated. the debuger output says: _1> OPENCVDLL.cpp 1>  OPENCVDLL.vcxproj -> C:\Users\...\OPENCVDLL\Debug\OPENCVDLL.dll_ I try another simple project without opencv dependencies, everithing work fine and i get the .lib file... strange. Any chance it could come frome the opencv libraries ?

Comment: The dll was not generated because of an error in my code. In the cpp file of the dll, i was doing _OPENCVDLL::OPENCVDLLtriangulatePoints_ (namespace name) instead of _OpenCvWrapper::OPENCVDLLtriangulatePoints_ (class name). After I changed this, the code worked fine. Thanks to David, Andro47 and PaulMcKenize !

Answer (score 1):

The `lib` file is just the middleman between you executable and the `DLL.` It is called an `import library` needed for *implicit* linking.

Citing MSDN: (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9yd93633.aspx)

> With implicit linking, the executable using the DLL links to an import
>   library (.lib file) provided by the maker of the DLL. The operating
>   system loads the DLL when the executable using it is loaded.

Comment: Ok, so what am I suppose to do ? create a lib file ? I don't understand why, because the tutorial is doesn't talk about that, what I have done is suppose to work, isn't it (I'm not really use to c++ and all this thing)

Comment: When you built the DLL, the lib file should also automatically have been built.  Look in your folders for such a file.  As a matter of fact, that link you posted in your question has this: `// compile with: /EHsc /link MathFuncsDll.lib`